# My own interactor style: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';'

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk

i am on a vtk project I wanted to write my own mouse interactor style i writed this class

```
class vtkInteractorStyleZoom : public vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera 
{
  public:
    static vtkInteractorStyleZoom* New();
    vtkTypeMacro(vtkInteractorStyleZoom, vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera);

    virtual void OnLeftButtonDown()
    {
        this->StartDolly();
    }


};

vtkStandardNewMacro(vtkInteractorStyleZoom);
```

when i compiled the project with cmake, i got this error :  expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';' token
 vtkStandardNewMacro(vtkInteractorStyleZoom);

Comment: What does `vtkTypeMacro(vtkInteractorStyleZoom, vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera);` do?

Comment: i take the architecture of the class from here [link](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/InteractorStyleSubclass) ! i dont know what it does exactly but the problem is with the last line vtkStandardNewMacro(vtkInteractorStyleZoom);
and not vtkTypeMacro(vtkInteractorStyleZoom, vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera);

Comment: i.e. did you include the header that defines all macros used in this code? This is why you should post _all_ of your code, not just the bit you think is relevant; if you just post a fragment, we can only speculate about what may or may not be above/below it in the real source file.

Comment: thx , this is the problem , i didn't include all the header that defines the macros , i take all this headears from the example that i putted above

Comment: @Jasseur Great, glad it worked. So, please mark your thread as a duplicate of that one.